# Async POST request in Java for Android

Tags: java, android, post, asynchronous, http-post

```
 public void btnWeb_Click(View view){
     String url="http://localhost/test/index.php";

     List<NameValuePair> dict = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
     dict.add(new BasicNameValuePair("url",url));
     dict.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "3"));

     PostReq postreq= new PostReq();
     postreq.execute(dict);

     String result="";
     while(result==""){ result= postreq.content;}  
     System.out.println(result); }
```

`PostReq` is the class that executes the Post request to the server asynchronously.

The problem is that if I do not put the `while`, the print function to print the variable RESULT as empty because it did not wait for the thread `postreq.execute(dict)` complete the operation.

I forced the wait with a `WHILE` but `WHILE` that blocks the main thread.

How Do I wait until the method is executed and then assign the value to the variable `RESULT` asynchronously?

For example, in C # for Windows Phone, I did it this way:

```
 async void button_click() {
    Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    dict.Add("id", "3");
string url="http://localhost/test/index.php";
    PostReq pr= new PostReq(url,dict);
    String risposta = await pr.getRisposta(); }
```

With Java for Android instead how can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at AsyncTask. It is not a good idea to be checking for results repeatedly in a while loop for a result from another thread.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: mmh.. a practical example of how to use AsyncTask in my case?

Comment: the example in the link I provided should give you an idea on how to implement.in doInBackground() you would do your POST and in onPostExecute() you would check your results. Please accept the answer if it helped you.